# Measure space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ where $L^p(X,\mathcal{F},\mu) \neq L^q(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ if $p\neq q$

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to solve this problem:

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space  where $L^p(X,\mathcal{F},\mu) \neq L^q(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ when $p\neq q$. Prove that there exist a sequence of sets 
$(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(A_i)>0$ and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ when $i \neq j$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a quick note, do you mean $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $p \neq q$. Since $L^q \neq L^p$, we can choose either $f \in L^p \backslash L^q$ or $f \in L^q \backslash L^p$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that there exists $f \in L^q \backslash L^p$ (otherwise we interchange the roles of $p$ and $q$).

The sets $B_k$ defined by

$$B_k := \{k \leq |f| < k+1\} \in \mathcal{F}, \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}_0,$$

are pairwise disjoint. Moreover, since $f \in L^q$, we have by Markov's inequality

$$\mu(B_k) \leq \frac{1}{k^q} \int |f|^q \, d\mu < \infty$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, it follows from

$$\infty = \int |f|^p \, d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{B_k} |f|^p \, d\mu \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mu(B_k) |k+1|^p$$

that $\mu(B_k)>0$ for infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Consequently, we can choose a subsequence $(B_{k_i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (B_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mu(B_{k_i})>0$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Setting $A_i := B_{k_i}$ finishes the proof.